# How to turn on product count in FacetedSearch?

Tags: commercetools

I have a question. I am using `ProductAttributeFacetedSearchSearchModel` to build `FacetedSearchExpression` but in result set I see only sku `count` and `productCount` is null. How to turn on it?

```
public FacetedSearchExpression<ProductProjection> createFacet(ProductAttributeFacetedSearchSearchModel productSearchModel) {
        final String attributeName = getFacetModel().getAttributeName();
        final String attributeValue = getFacetModel().getAttributeValue();
        return productSearchModel.ofBoolean(attributeName).is(attributeValue);
    }
```

Json that I've got from CT, for search I am using ofBoolean() to search by boolean attribute:

```
{
    "facetResults": [
        {
            "type": "terms",
            "missing": 903,
            "total": 903,
            "other": 0,
            "terms": [
                {
                    "term": "true",
                    "count": 713,
                    "productCount": null
                },
                {
                    "term": "false",
                    "count": 190,
                    "productCount": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your question. Have you reviewed the platform docs for this topic?
Under facet terms you can see that product count will only be available if counting products is enabled.

https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-products-search#facetterm

If you are still having difficulty it would be helpful if you could provide an example of the query you are using and the response body you receive.

Comment: Attached a code. How to enable product count in this case?

Comment: `FacetSearchModel` has a `withCountingProducts` method. But I am using `FacetedSearchSearchModel` and it does not have this method. How to enable a product count in `FacetedSearchSearchModel`?

Comment: I would use the way described in the docs: http://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/io/sphere/sdk/meta/SearchDocumentation.html#faceting in which you have more control over the facet expressions.

Comment: I mean when I've got a json (attached it to post) I have only sku count and productCount is equals to null. In getTotal I've got a sum of all skus in each product. The question is. How can I to turn on the product count?